# Liferay/Java Custom Login through ADFS

Tags: java, authentication, liferay, saml-2.0, adfs

Using Liferay CE 6.2 GA2. Client is using ADFS

Have a custom login screen in Liferay 6.2 where I need to connect to client's ADFS to authenticate a user based on the User id and password that he/she enters and retrieve some basic user attributes like email, groups, etc.

How can I do this? Does ADFS have any endpoints that I can use to authenticate?
Liferay SAML EE Plugin - Configuring Liferay as SP and ADFS as IDP is not possible as it forwards the user to the IDP's login page. Please note that this is a custom login screen and SSO is out of the picture.

Comment: Turns out SAML is the way to go :)

Comment: So... Did you get actual ADFS working? Does the user still need to type in credentials? Did you install the plugin? What actually happened here? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay can connect to your LDAP, including AD, thus there's no need for a custom login screen. Use this route and make your life easy and your setup maintainable. From that point on you can continue to evaluate SAML and other SSO means.

As 98% of people that assume they need custom login mechanism actually don't need them (they just need to be pointed to the internal mechanism and its extension points), I'm assuming that you're among this majority, and you'd have to provide a lot of information to convince me of the opposite. So start properly connecting through LDAP and assume that you can actually use SSO

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Here custom login screen is just an hook overriding the default Liferay login jsp. I worked on LDAP authentication in Liferay previously. The client does not have an LDAP server. Only ADFS. I'm not really sure how to authenticate Liferay through ADFS. Any pointers there would really help me out. And I'm looking forward to your "Developing Ridiculously Small Plugins" dev.life session :)